# Dependency error installing Meteorite on Centos 6.4 (64 bit)

Tags: meteor, meteorite

i'm newer using NodeJs and trying to install Meteorite NPM.
But the following error occurs:

```
[root@meteor /]# npm install -g meteorite
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ddp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.3.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wrench/1.3.9
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt/0.2.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.2.9
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rolling_timeout_exec
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.3.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ddp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wrench/1.3.9
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt/0.2.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.2.9
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rolling_timeout_exec
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/faye-websocket
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteor-ejson
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-srp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/read
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/revalidator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/winston
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/meteor-ejson
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/faye-websocket
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-srp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket-driver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/read
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/winston
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/revalidator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cycle
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket-driver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cycle
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream
/usr/bin/mrt -> /usr/lib/node_modules/meteorite/bin/mrt.js

> meteorite@0.7.2 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/meteorite
> sh ./completions/postinstall.sh

npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/block-stream requires inherits@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/fstream requires inherits@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/fstream-ignore requires inherits@'2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/fstream-npm requires inherits@'2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/glob requires inherits@'2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/npmconf requires inherits@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/tar requires inherits@'2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
meteorite@0.7.2 /usr/lib/node_modules/meteorite
âââ rolling_timeout_exec@0.0.1
âââ colors@0.6.0-1
âââ wrench@1.3.9
âââ async@0.2.9
âââ underscore@1.3.3
âââ optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.8)
âââ ddp@0.4.4 (faye-websocket@0.7.2, meteor-ejson@0.6.3, node-srp@0.0.1)
âââ fstream@0.1.25 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@2.0.3, rimraf@2.2.6, mkdirp@0.3.5)
âââ prompt@0.2.11 (revalidator@0.1.6, pkginfo@0.3.0, utile@0.2.1, winston@0.6.2, read@1.0.5)
[root@meteor /]#
```

PS: Git (1.7.1-3.el6_4.1) and NodeJs (0.10.26-1.el6 - via yum from epel repo.) are installed.

How can i solve this dependecy errors?
Tnks!

Comment: did you try if meteorite is actually working or not? those seem to be just warnings. what happens when you run `mrt create testapp`

Comment: Yes, but fail too. execvp(): No such file or directory
Can't find meteor executable! and when i try to install again Meteor show: The latest version of Meteor, 0.8.0, is already installed on this computer.

Comment: you may need to remove the current installation and install again with `sudo -H npm install -g meteorite`

Comment: Works fine! Now i can use `mrt create` Thank you.

Comment: great, I recorded it as an answer.

Comment: Serkan, if a change user like `sudo su` dont find meteor command in bash. Eg. I log by default with vagrant user, meteor command works, if i change to root and came back to vagrant user again, meteor command not found. What -H flag do?

Comment: That's normal because when you're installing with sudo -H, you're elevating your privileges while keeping your target home your user's home, not root's. This way, you don't need sudo or su any more when running meteor commands. If you don't use -H, than you have to always use sudo or get to sudo su.

Answer (score 0):

When meteorite has a hard time meeting dependencies or finding libraries, you will have to make sure remove the current installation and reinstall it using:

```
$ sudo -H npm install -g meteorite
```

note the `-H` flag.